# Show that two Riemannian manifolds are isometric.

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry

Let $\mathbb B^n(R)$ the ball of radius $R$ centered at the origin in $\mathbb R^n$, with the metric given in coordinates $(u_1,\cdots,u_n)$ by :
$$h_B=\dfrac{4R^4}{(R^2-|u|^2)^2}\sum_{i=1}^n(du_i)^2$$
and $\mathbb U^n(R)$ be the Ponincaré half space model in $\mathbb R^n$ defined in coordinates $(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ by $\mathbb U^n(R)=\{(x,y) :y>0\}$, endowed with the metric $$h_U=\dfrac{R^2}{y^2}\left (\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (dx_i)^2 +(dy)^2\right)$$
Let now $k :\mathbb B^n(R) \to \mathbb U^n(R)$ be the generelized cayley transformation, and $k^{-1}$ its inverse defined by $$k^{-1}(x,y)=(u,v)=\left( \frac{2R^2x}{|x|^2+(y+R)^2}, R\frac{|x|^2+y^2-R^2}{|x|^2+(y+R)^2} \right) $$
I want to show that $$(k^{-1})^*h_B=h_U$$

---

\begin{align*}(k^{-1})^*h_B&= (k^{-1})^*\left( \frac{4R^2}{(R^2-\sum_{i=0}^n (u_i)^2} \sum_{i=1}^n (du_i)^2\right) \\ &= 4R^4 \dfrac{ \left(\displaystyle   \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} d\left( \dfrac{2R^2x_i}{|x|^2+(y+R)^2} \right)^2 +d\left( R\dfrac{|x|^2+y^2-R^2}{|x|^2+(y+R)^2} \right)^2\right)}{\left( R^2-  \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \left( \dfrac{2R^2x_i}{|x|^2+(y+R)^2} \right)^2 - \left( R\dfrac{|x|^2+y^2-R^2}{|x|^2+(y+R)^2} \right)^2\right)^2 } \end{align*}
First question : Is this formula true ? I get stuck in calculation since two days ! So any help is highly appreciated !

**N.B:** this exercice is **problem 3.4 page 80 in John M.Lee introduction to Riemannian manifolds**

Comment: Your last formula is missing a square in the denominator. Other than that, you're on the right track. As I wrote in the book, it's basically a *long* calculation. After you compute the differentials, you can do a lot of simplifying based on bilinearity and commutativity of symmetric products of $1$-forms.

Comment: Thank you so much Sir ! I edit the formula ! @JackLee